# Terraform vSphere foreach iterate problem

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-provider-vsphere

I need a help again.

I need to generate network interfaces dynamically. For this purpose i declare interfaces in the vm config like this:

```
`virtual_machines = {
  "gw" = {
    template = "cent7_template"
    host_name = "gw"
        domain_name = "contoso.com"
    dns_server_list = ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]

    num_cpus = 2
    memory = 2048
    interfaces = [
          {
            ipv4_address = "192.168.5.240"
        ipv4_netmask = "24"
            network = "VM Network"
      },
          {
            ipv4_address = "10.10.0.1"
        ipv4_netmask = "24"
            network = "Contoso Lan"
      }
    ]

    gateway = "192.168.5.251"
  }


  "lab" = {
    template = "cent7_template"
    host_name = "lab"
        domain_name = "contoso.com"
    dns_server_list = ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]

    num_cpus = 2
    memory = 2048
    interfaces = [
          {
            ipv4_address = "10.10.0.2"
        ipv4_netmask = "24"
            network = "Contoso Lan"
      }
    ]

    gateway = "10.10.0.1"
  }

}`
```

To iterate through interfaces and generate it as data source i created local:

```
locals {
  networks = flatten([
    for vm_key, objects in var.virtual_machines : [
      for interface in objects.interfaces : {
          network           = interface.network
          ipv4_address = interface.ipv4_address
          ipv4_netmask  = interface.ipv4_netmask
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

And dynamic data source:

```
data "vsphere_network" "interfaces" {
  for_each      = {for idx, val in local.networks: idx => val}
  name          = each.value.network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
```

But this resource code generates all of the interfaces that are declared in all vm's. For example, my first vm have 2 interfaces(VM Network and Contoso Lan), my second interface have 1 interface
Contoso Lan and my code want to create 3 interfaces in summary but i need to create interfaces that are declared for VM.

```
  dynamic "network_interface" {
        for_each        = {for idx, val in local.networks: idx => val}
        content{
          network_id    = data.vsphere_network.interfaces[network_interface.key].id
        }
  }
```

Data sources are also generated 3 times.

I need to create only interfaces that are declared for this vm and not for all vms. How can i achieve this?

Thank you for answers!

Resource definition:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {

  for_each         = var.virtual_machines

  name             = "terra-${each.key}.${each.value.domain_name}"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_host.host.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id

  num_cpus         = each.value.num_cpus
  memory           = each.value.memory
  guest_id         = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].guest_id

  disk {
        label            = "disk0"
        size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks[0].size
        thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks[0].thin_provisioned
  }

  dynamic "network_interface" {
        for_each        = {for idx, val in local.networks: idx => val}
        content{
          network_id    = data.vsphere_network.interfaces[network_interface.key].id
        }
  }

  clone {
        template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].id

        customize {
          linux_options {
                host_name = "${each.key}.${each.value.domain_name}"
                domain    = each.value.domain_name
          }

                  dynamic "network_interface" {
                          for_each        = {for idx, val in local.networks: idx => val}

                          content {
                                ipv4_address = network_interface.value.ipv4_address
                                ipv4_netmask = network_interface.value.ipv4_netmask
                        }
                  }

          ipv4_gateway    = each.value.gateway
        }
  }
}
```

Locals:

```
locals {
  networks = flatten([
    for vm_key, objects in var.virtual_machines : [
      for interface in objects.interfaces : {
          network           = interface.network
          ipv4_address = interface.ipv4_address
          ipv4_netmask  = interface.ipv4_netmask
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Comment: Where and how `dynamic "network_interface"` is used? What is the resource definition? Also its not clear why having 3 interfaces is incorrect if 1 +2  is three. All seem to be fine.

Comment: In vm1 config where are 2 interfaces, in vm2 config where is 1 interface. When dynamic block is applied - there are 3 interfaces for both vms are created because this construction is iterate through all of the interfaces of all of the vm conifgs. I think i can rewrite it witch count but interesting is it possible make it with "foreach".

Comment: You haven't provided resource definition. What is the full context of your `dynamic "network_interface"`?

Comment: oh sorry, have added it to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to flatten your networks this way, as this will give you map, not list, with keys `vmname-ipaddress`:

```
 
locals {
  networks = merge([
    for vm_key, objects in var.virtual_machines : {
      for interface in objects.interfaces : 
        "${vm_key}-${interface.ipv4_address}"  => {   
          network           = interface.network
          ipv4_address = interface.ipv4_address
          ipv4_netmask  = interface.ipv4_netmask
      }
  }]...)
}
```

then

```
data "vsphere_network" "interfaces" {
  for_each      = local.networks
  name          = each.value.network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
```

and finally you get correct NI using the key `vmname-ipaddress` in the loop:

```
  dynamic "network_interface" {
        for_each        = each.value.interfaces
        content{
          network_id    = data.vsphere_network.interfaces["${each.key}-${network_interface.value.ipv4_address}"].id
        }
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in dynamic "network_interface" block:  This object does not have an attribute named "ipv4_address".                                                                     80:           network_id    = data.vsphere_network.interfaces["${each.key}-${network_interface.ipv4_address}"].id

Comment: @RomanQwertoff Try now. I updated the answer.

Comment: sorry, my fault. Forget to add value before ipv4_address.Ofcource ["${each.key}-${network_interface.value.ipv4_address}"].id. Thank, Marcin, again! Very grateful to you!

Comment: yeah, thank you! Update please "for_each        = each.interfaces" > "for_each        = each.value.interfaces" for the same dummies like me )